# Create getter and setter members for a C++ class in Vim

Tags: c++, vim

I'm creating a class with many double (or something else, the type doesn't matter) members.

```
class CalcParameters {
public:
  CalcParameters() {}
  ~CalcParameters() {}

  // getters and setters here

private:
  double _param1;
  double _param2;
  ...
};
```

Is it possible, in Vim, to write a script to automatically generate public getters and setters for every parameter?

like

```
double param1() const { return _param1; }
void setParam1(double param1) { _param1 = param1; }
...
```

**Note**:

This code is not a snippet from real code but only something I wrote to illustrate the  question. On my real working code the members are named and setters have validation logic besides the attribution. But when writing a skeleton class with all members it would be nice to let Vim create the basic getters and setters for me. Is this possible?

Comment: You probably have a problem in your object design. You should never need "many getters and setters".

Comment: @dark_charlie It's a class with parameters to be consumed by another class with simulation logic. How else could I design it? Anyway, it's mostly a throw away test code. I was mostly curious if I could automate this in Vim.

Comment: I think you should back up from this a bit. Instead of asking how to implement this design, tell us about what you're trying to accomplish, and ask about how to design code to accomplish that.

Comment: If you are just going to let a value be set to what ever and not put any sort of logic behind the set why not just make them public?

Comment: I am also just say that if Vim supports scripts, then yes I am sure you can do this, if Vim does not support scripts, then no, you can't write a script to do this.

Comment: @thecoshman Yes, you're right. As I said in other comment I was mostly curious if I could automate this in Vim than on how my class really look - the given snippet is not representative of actual code.

Comment: @thecoshman - since C++ treats variable and function access differently (unlike a language like say C# or VB) it is important to use function syntax for get/set rather than direct access.  Otherwise when you change the internals of the class to calculate one or more values rather than simply storing a variable, you have a lot more code to change that shouldn't need changing.  It's a similar reason why you're better off providing protected member function access to private variables rather than making those variables protected.

Comment: This could indeed be done with a Vim macro. Quite easily, in fact. But this code is broken anyway. @Vitor Py: I'd suggest rethinking your design instead of using the editor to automate something you shouldn't be doing in the first place.

Comment: Private member variables should not use a `_` prefix.  This is reserved for platform library code.  Use the `m_` prefix, or the `_` suffix instead to avoid problems.

Comment: @Charles Salvia This is interesting to know. Is this on the standard?

Comment: @Vitor, the practice of private member variables with `m_` prefixes or `_` suffixes is not mandated by any standard, but merely a widely practiced convention.

Comment: @Charles Salvia Charles, yes. I was talking about using m_ instead of the _ suffix.

Comment: @Charles: _ + lowercase letter is fine for a member name.  It's only _ + uppercase that's globally reserved.

Comment: @Roger:  There are some rules for what is and is not permissible with leading underscores (depending on the next character and the linkage).  I prefer to avoid the whole issue by not having leading underscores.

Comment: @David: Yes, there are 3 simple rules on reserved identifiers involving underscores.  Should we "avoid the whole issue" by forbidding underscores in our identifiers?

Comment: @Roger:  I have one rule:  don't use leading or double underscores.  Nice and simple, and unlikely to give the most ignorant novice the idea of using underscore-uppercase.

Comment: @David: I've found ignoring how C++ really works is rarely a good idea, but even when it is, it comes back to bite you in the ass later.  How long does it take to explain?  1) Don't use adjacent underscores. 2) Don't use leading underscores followed by uppercase. 3) Don't use leading underscores for globally scoped identifiers (and note how this includes extern "C", which you mentioned).  And #3 is reinforced because we teach novices to use namespaces, right?

Comment: @Roger:  Ignoring how C++ really works works as long as you're conservative about it.  If I'm a little more restrictive than the standard requires, I'm still writing valid programs.  If I'm a little less restrictive than the standard requires, I'm asking for trouble.  And thanks for correcting my mistaken "linkage".

Comment: @David: I wasn't correcting anything, just pointing out that the problem you mentioned is included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a [ftplugin for this purpose](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhCpp) a long time ago.

The idea is to type `;AA` and to answer the questions Vim asks you. It has a primitive form of const-correctness understanding (i.e. an `int` would be copied while a `string` would be exchanged by const-ref)

I should rewrite it some day now that I know how to fetch the type of an already written data member, plus several [functions aimed at converting identifiers](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/dev/trunk/autoload/lh/dev/naming.vim) (member <-> getter <-> setter <-> parameter <-> local variable <-> constant / underscore separated words <-> lower/upper camel cases). Alas I've been introduced to [Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) and I tend to minimize my use of getters and setters and hence my need to modernize the ftplugin.

EDIT: Since then, I've written two new refactoring methods for my [lh-refactor](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhRefactor) plugin: *Extract Setter* and *Extract Getter*. As explained above, the extraction methods know how to build the names of the setter and the getter from the name of the member variable.

Answer (score 3):

For simple data classes, another nice option sometimes is to use a [`boost::tuple`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html) (or `std::tuple` in C++0x):

```
typedef tuple<int, char> MyDataElement;
MyDataElement data = make_tuple(1,'c');
int whatever = get<0>(data); // 1
```

Also, thinking it twice, you also may consider using [Boost Property Map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/property_map/doc/property_map.html).

Finally, as for the VIM script, it certainly can be done. I've been investigating a little bit, and you can do something like this (assuming you identify member variables with a prefix, say `m_`):

```
:let bl = getbufline("" ,1, "$")
```

this will load all the lines of the buffer, then, filter them by those that contain something "m_":

```
:let xx = filter(bl, 'v:val =~ "m_.*"')
```

then you can investigate how to extract actual variable names from the array `xx`, and so on.

Comment: This would work for fixed length container of varying param types

Comment: @Steve: Well data-only (POD) classes can be seen this way, plus the names for each param, not present in the tuple.

Answer (score 2):

If this is really the way your class looks, store them in order in a `vector<double>` and provide a single getter by `size_t` index into the `vector`, along with a separate `paramCount()` method to measure the vector length using `size()`.

Comment: My class doesn't look like this. I have a set of named parameters (like pH, concentration, diffusivity, ...). I actually already wrote the class and 7 or 8 getters/setters pairs it had but I was curious if I could automate this in Vim.

Comment: @Vitor Py - I see - that makes more sense if they are not generic, as your code looks.  Thanks for context.  I guess since they are all `double`, you could index them using an `enum`, but still not really answering your q.

Answer (score 0):

Move the relevant data outside of the `private` section and into a `public` section. Nobody said all member data must be private: if it's part of the interface then it should be public, and the hell with those verbose, redundant, silly getters and setters.

In programming, if something can be done by a script then it shouldn't be done.

Comment: I added a note to give some context on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It *is* possible to use Vim in this way.

[VimCasts has a relevant video](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/converting-haml-to-erb-with-vim-macros/) which describes one of the simpler ways of automating processes like these, with nothing more than a macro, marks, and a little yanking and pasting.

**But this is not how I would approach your problem.** Instead, I would type `:q!` and **start over.** Almost invariably, the use of getters and setters in C++ is poor style, and inadvisable.